# How do I redirect to specific path?

Tags: angular, redirect, angular2-routing

I have the following routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: InvestmentsCenterContainerComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '', component: InvestmentsCenter,
                children: [ {
                    path: ':id',
                    children: [ {
                        path: '',
                        component: InvestmentsListComponent,
                        resolve: { investmentsData: InvestmentsDetailResolver },

                    } ]
                } ]
            }, {
                path: 'investment', component: InvestmentDetailComponent // <- cannot navigate to here
            }

        ]
    },

];
```

After a user clicks on a button inside the InvestmentsListComponents, I want to redirect him to the `InvestmentDetailComponent`:

I am using the following to attempt the redirection:

```
this.router.navigate([ '/investment' ]).then(( d ) => console.log(d));
```

However this does not redirect me anywhere, I tried putting the appropriate path in the `Routes` under the children of `path: ':id;` but still with no result. I also tried to navigate with the `relativeTo` attribute with no avail.

It is worth noting that the above routes have a parent path:

```
path: 'investments'
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the parent path?

Comment: @echonax investments, I am loading its module in the main app routing file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a `/` when navigating, it will act as an absolute path.

So in this case the correct route should be

```
this.router.navigate([ '/investments/investment' ]).then(( d ) => console.log(d));
```

More info: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#relative-navigation

Comment: I see, but this does not load the InvestmentDetailComponent. What if I want to redirect with respect to the `:id`  ?

Comment: @Predator44 what does it load? any errors? If you want to navigate w.r.t something you can take a look at `relativeTo` parameter.

Comment: not at all, but the promise returned is false. Anyway this answer placed me on the correct path, so I consider it an acceptable answer. Thank you.